# libcurl: curl_global_init - потоко-небезопасен

Tags: c++, c, curl

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот в документации Libcurl сказано, что функция curl_global_init():

> Эта функция должна быть вызвана хотя бы один раз в программе

и

> This function is not thread safe. You must not call it when any other
> thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is
> running.
>
> Эта функция не является потокобезопасной. Вы не должны вызывать его,
> когда работает любой другой поток в программе (т. Е. Поток,
> использующий ту же память).

Вот вроде бы отдельно слова понимаю, а общий смысл, как то не доходит.
Что значит - "Вы не должны вызывать его, когда работает любой другой поток в программе" ?

То есть, если я создал хотя бы еще один тред в коде, и в этом треде выполнятся все, что угодно, только не libcurl или вообще я поток сразу усыпил, то curl_global_init - нельзя вызывать ?

И дополнительный не понятный момент:

> Если вы еще не вызывали curl_global_init , **curl_easy_init** сделает
> это автоматически. Это может привести к летальному исходу в
> многопоточных случаях, поскольку curl_global_init не является
> потокобезопасным, и может привести к проблемам с ресурсами из-за
> отсутствия соответствующей очистки.

Прямо не сказано, но правильно ли я понимаю, что вызов curl_global_init() перед curl_easy_init() - укажет функции curl_easy_init() не вызывать curl_global_init() ?

Comment: Всего-то и делов, вызовите его в main, до того, как сделали другие потоки.

Comment: global_init после успешного вызова взводит влаг initialized, который потом [проверяется](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/2b3dd01b779e4eff623a735792a915cde914b74a/lib/easy.c#L295) в easy_init.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Что значит - "Вы не должны вызывать его, когда работает любой другой поток в программе" ?

Ровно это и значит.

> То есть, если я создал хотя бы еще один тред в коде, и в этом треде выполнятся все, что угодно, только не libcurl или вообще я поток сразу усыпил, то curl_global_init - нельзя вызывать ?

Здесь так написано, да. Не важно что за поток, в любом случае нельзя.

Другое дело, что это скорее всего неправда, и они просто перестраховываются. Дальше есть пояснение:

> You must not call it when any other thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is running. This does not just mean no other thread that is using libcurl. Because curl_global_init calls functions of other libraries that are similarly thread unsafe, it could conflict with any other thread that uses these other libraries.

Т.е. они зовут не-потокобезопасные функции некоторых других библиотек, и беспокоятся о том, что ваш поток тоже их вызовет. Можно разведать, что там за библиотеки, и избегать конкретно их в параллельных потоках.